# Swing - waiting for rendering to finish

Tags: java, swing, kotlin, task, event-dispatch-thread

I have a little problem. I am trying to display very large text in JTextPane (~ 10 MB). I want to show a worker dialog (with animated gif as an indefinite progress bar) until the text is rendered by JTextPane.

So far, I came with this (kotlin):

```
val worker = WorkerWindow(this, "Drawing text...") // JDialog
SwingUtilities.invokeLater {
    worker.isVisible = true
}
SwingUtilities.invokeLater {
    textPane.document = logcat.document // Long UI operation
    worker.dispose()
}
```

Sadly, the dialog is dismissed immediately, before the rendering of document finishes. Is there any sort of callback, i can use when EDT finishes an operation or something?

[image: Worker dialog]

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at Swing workers here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/SwingWorker.html This will allow you to have more control over async tasks in swing.

Separate question: Why not set worker window visibility and load the document in one thread? Like this:

```
val worker = WorkerWindow(this, "Drawing text...") // JDialog

SwingUtilities.invokeLater {
    worker.isVisible = true
    textPane.document = logcat.document // Long UI operation
    worker.dispose()
}
```

Seems easier...

Comment: Oh, actually i just noticed, that updating the document on background thread will cause the JTextPane to update! thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out!

```
val worker = WorkerWindow(this, "Drawing text...")
Thread {
    textPane.document = logcat.document
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater {
        worker.dispose()
    }
}.start()
SwingUtilities.invokeLater {
    worker.isVisible = true
}
```